# Reading Ctrl + until found a non-digit from keyboard

Tags: c#, c, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, key

It's possible once <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was pressed, get all keys pressed before until a non-digit was found? valid inputs:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> `// do something with 1`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>  `// do something with 2`

`//..`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>30</kbd> `// do something with 30`

it's a will works as the <kbd>FN</kbd> keys, but instead of it, I wan to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and extend the range from `0-9` to `0-50`. I hope this is clean. Thanks in advance.

Note: I tagged `C#` and `C` languages because either of these languages is valid for my use case.

Comment: globally or only while your program has focus?

Comment: With Ctrl-30, will Ctrl-3 be processed?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: globally.

Comment: @jcolebrand: e.g Ctrl + 30a `a` in this input is the non-digit.

Comment: hmm can't think of anything better than a global low level keyboard hook.

Comment: @tiwo: must be tested if the next character is a digit. e.g, input: Ctrl+30a will "reading" until found the `a` letter, that's a non-digit.

Comment: I think it's not possible. I will remove the question..

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use AutoHotKey(http://www.autohotkey.com/). Even then, it might be slightly difficult, but much, much easier than writing it in C.

Comment: Those combinations will interfere with application specific hotkeys. Many applications use Ctrl+NumerKey as a hotkey. Are you sure you really want this?

Answer (score 0):

A low level keyboard hook should be able to do this. Use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. You can find some C# implementations on the Internet.

I generally discourage the use of keyboard hooks due to their global side effects, but I can't think of anything else that fulfills your requirements.